# How to pipe stdout/stderr to the stdin of another command in Turtle?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

The title pretty much says it all, I couldn't locate this answer obviously worded in the docs.  I'm also unclear on how one would save-off stdout/stderr in a variable for later use to piping to stdin for multiple commands.  Something conceptually like the below where `x <- shell a b` means getting the stdout from the shell command and storing it in `x`

---

```
pipeThings = do
  c1out <- shell "some-cmd" empty
  ... do some things
  c1out `pipe` shell "another-cmd" empty
  c1out `pipe` shell "yet-another-cmd" empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of the existence of [`inshellWithErr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.4.1/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:inshellWithErr)?

Comment: This looks like it would do the job.  I was searching around for the 'pipe' keyword and not finding anything.  Should have just searched more broadly for stderr.